# Custom Workflow: timed-out at the Sandbox Client.System.TimeoutException

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

Currently we are working on CRM 2015 Online, we have a requirement to backfill a field, “new_UniqueNumber”. For that we have written a custom workflow (OnDemand|Async.). The WF expects to retrieves 3500+ records in a single go (considering RetriveMultiple limit 5000).

The WF only works for around 1600 records and then breaks into TimeOut exception :

```
Unhandled Exception:
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: The plug-in execution failed because the operation
has timed-out at the Sandbox Client.System.TimeoutException: Microsoft Dynamics
CRM has experienced an error.
at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.Execute(IExecutionContext context)
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ProxyCustomActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext
executionContext)
```

Also, Instead of trying to work on all the records at once, we tried to do it in a batch (i.e. limiting query.PageInfo.Count) and using paging, but this didn’t helped.

What do you think?

Comment: Can you post your query. What fetch are you using: QueryExpression, Fetchxml? Are you fetching all colums of the entity? Try to limit the columns that you are fetching. This could help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want just to populate a field why do you use custom workflow activity? Develop simple .Net application or use SSIS for performing that job.

Comment: Because, 
1. This is one-time update that will update some existing records.(OnDemand for Back filling).
2. a. There were limited records for around 7000 to update.
b. Yes, we can use .Net App, But, what I am wondering was it would also need to invoke RetrieveMultiple.
3. My concern is only that, why it didn't succeeded when we are approaching it in batches and  with Async win. service. Moreover, customer would like to have WF for this.

Comment: Please refer to my thread on MSDN for further details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab4fc970-8751-46e7-bfb5-3fb24c018696/custom-workflow-timedout-at-the-sandbox-clientsystemtimeoutexception?forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: I believe that I've already answered you on your question at mentioned thread. There are not a lot of specialists who works with Dynamics CRM and hold name Andrii Butenko. Anyway I haven't seen any valuable reason why you can't use .Net App or SSIS instead of workflow/custom workflow activity.

Comment: I agree with using a .NET app or SSIS data flow. It can be a simple console application which will give you the advantage of throttling the batch size of recorda to update. Most of all you can debug execution when testing and will give you hopefully more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having two different workflows? One workflow that retrieves the thousands of records, and then invokes a second workflow on each of the records to actually do the work?

Then the 2-minute timeout wouldn't be a problem for the workflow that simply calls a thousand workflows (because they should be created just fine -- but may stay in "Waiting for Resources" for a few minutes), and the timeout should not be an issue for each of the "child" workflows, if each of them completes within 2-minutes of starting.